# Android: Is it safely to store global listeners in global list?

Tags: android

*Sorry for my English*

I have some class that has static (== `global`) methods such as `setListener()`, `removeListener()`. It stores quite few listeners (which are `global`) and these listeners take very low memory.

But what will happen if the system kills my app's activity because of the lack memory for other application?

Could happen that the system will remove these global listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the system kills your app, it kills the VM - static variables are lost.

Depending on what you're doing, you probably don't want to register short lived listeners in a static way.

Comment: Then, it is safely add global listener in `onResume()` and remove it in `onPause()` ?